# JavaScript timer is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a file named `ExtremeNotifications.js` and added to the `_Layout.cshtml` master layout.

The ExtremeNotifications.js includes the following JavaScript code:

```
var extremeNotifications = extremeNotifications || {};

extremeNotifications = (function () {

    var baseURL = document.baseURI;
    var url = baseURL + 'api/usernotifications';
    var isNotificationServiceStarted = false;
    var timer;

    function getPendingNotifications() {
        $.ajax({ url: url, success: dataRetrieved, type: 'GET', dataType: 'json' });
    }

    function dataRetrieved(data) {
        alert(data);
    }

    function startNotifications() {
        if (!isNotificationServiceStarted) {
            timer = setInterval(getPendingNotifications, 3000);
            isNotificationServiceStarted = true;
        }
    }

    function stopNotifications() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        isNotificationServiceStarted = false;
    }

    return {
        start: startNotifications(),
        getPendingNotifications: getPendingNotifications(),
        isNotificationServiceStarted: isNotificationServiceStarted,
        stop: stopNotifications()
    }
})();
```

Then in my Home `Index.cshtml` I start the notifications with the following code and only if `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`:

```
<script>
   extremeNotifications.start();
</script>
```

So now when my page starts and I'm authenticated user I get an alert box in the first time but I never see another alert after 3 seconds.

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but you're creating that returned object incorrectly:

```
return {
    start: startNotifications,
    getPendingNotifications: getPendingNotifications,
    isNotificationServiceStarted: isNotificationServiceStarted,
    stop: stopNotifications
};
```

By including the `()` after the function names, your code was *calling* the functions and returning their return values instead of returning references to the functions themselves.

Comment: oops! Forgot that, had so long to write JavaScript! It Works now, thanks.